# Swift: my destinationVC segue is showing nil

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having users fill out some profile information via texts fields (name, email, etc.), which is used to set my ProfileContoller.shared.profile values. When I get to my navigation segue to pass the data over, my destinationVC.profile will not set its value to the sending profile object and I get nil instead.

My sendingVC is embedded in a navigation controller, while my destinationVC is embedded in Tab Bar Controller.

[Segue SendingVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzEy8.png)

[Attributes Inspector SendingVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHGYL.png)

[DestinationVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBTWq.png)

```
// Sending View Controller: 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let profile = ProfileController.shared.profile else { return }
    if segue.identifier == "signUpMemicTBC" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ProfileViewController
        destinationVC?.profile = profile

// Receiving ProfileViewController:
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var fullNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: - Landing Pad
    var profile : Profile? {
        didSet {
            updateViews()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateViews()
    }

    func updateViews () {
        guard let profile = profile else { return }
        fullNameLabel.text = profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName
        usernameLabel.text = profile.username
        emailLabel.text = profile.email
    }
}

// ProfileController:
class ProfileController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var profile : Profile?

    // MARK: - Singleton
    static let shared = ProfileController()

}
```

My sending object has data:
    (lldb) po profile
    Profile: 0x600000c873c0

The destination object is unexpectedly nil:
    (lldb) po destinationVC?.profile
    nil

Comment: Post your segue declaration on storyboard (print screen). Show your Attributes inspector's view controller

Comment: Is `ProfileController` and `ProfileViewController` are same ? Is it spell mistake in above code snippet ?

Comment: Okay got the images linked above.

Comment: Can you show your code for `ProfileController` and `ProfileViewController` ?

Comment: No, ProfileController is a model controller that holds my singleton and ProfileViewController is a UIViewController

Comment: Have you tried to `po destinationVC` ?

Comment: I get another nil value when I po destinationVC

Comment: @VRAwesome sure I just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`didSet` triggers while your vc in segue isn't loaded yet so all outlets are nil

you need to put  `updateViews()` inside `viewDidLoad`

---

Plus your destination is a tabBar

```
let tab = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
let destinationVC = tab.viewControllers![2] as! ProfileViewController
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried this as well. when I po profile after viewDidLoad, I still get nil

Comment: how to do you navigate `performSegue` or `present` ??

Comment: I believe performSegue, I don't think I've used present before

Comment: do `let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ProfileViewController` and attach the crash

Comment: SIGABRT - Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x110757300) to 'Memic.ProfileViewController' (0x103c810e0).
2019-05-30 13:01:16.666498-0600 Memic[13037:13192113] Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x110757300) to 'Memic.ProfileViewController' (0x103c810e0).

Comment: I thought that was it! Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x116c5e520) to 'Memic.ProfileViewController' (0x10a187108).
2019-05-30 13:16:01.123162-0600 Memic[13320:13200646] Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x116c5e520) to 'Memic.ProfileViewController' (0x10a187108).

Comment: it needs to be UIViewController not TableView

Comment: in which tab your profile vc exists inside the tab ?

Comment: You are not getting data in ProfileViewController because destination controller is UITabBarController. 
Convert your statement from 

   let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ProfileViewController

to 

```guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ProfileViewController else {
return
}
destinationVC.profile = profile


```

Comment: no this won't solve the problem , the destination of the segue is a tabController according to the crash not a vc

Comment: it's the third controller, not first - I don't know the syntax but trying to solve

Comment: awesome, thanks so.much! the data is going through, although the updateViews function on the destinationVC is unwrapping a nil, which is weird because I can po all the profile values - Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: don't use `didSet` use `viewDidLoad` and verify all outlets are connected and don't assign them inside the `prepare` also

Comment: @bhersh90
```let tab = segue.destination as! UITabBarController```
```let destinationVC = tab.viewControllers![2] as! ProfileViewController```. Using this level of unwrapping is not preferred because all these force unwrapping and using magic numbers to evaluate value at in array like ```tab.viewControllers![2]``` might land you in crash. I would recommend going through the answer I posted below once.

Comment: perfect. I really do appreciate the help

Comment: @AnkushBhatia your code doesn't make sense ,   if you aware and sure of something no need to worry about `!`

Comment: Thanks Ankush - I switched them all back to optionals and it seems to be working well

Comment: @bhersh90 poor design is writing a code which can lead you into trouble at some edge case at some point later which you are not aware of at this point of time. I feel you should be writing code which is scalable and dynamic. Feel free to follow up the discuss in the thread below.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is call the `updateViews()` in the main thread.

```
didSet {
        print("did set profile called")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{[weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            self.updateViews()
        }
    }
```

Another option would be to update the views in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let prof = self.profile {
        self.updateViews()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to safely pass data to the `ProfileViewController`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let profile = ProfileController.shared.profile else { return }
        if segue.identifier == "signUpMemicTBC" {
            guard let tabBarController = segue.destination as? UITabBarController else { return }
            guard let profileController = tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(at: 2) as? ProfileViewController else {
                return
            }
            profileController.profile = profile
        }
    }
```

Comment: this `first(where: { $0 is ProfileViewController }) as? ProfileViewController` doesn't make sense it' s should be a search for a vc that i'm sure it's an index 2

Comment: Using magic numbers is not preferred.. Let's suppose some other developer started working on this code later and requirement states to move this controller to different tab. The code I have written is more dynamic as compared to ```tab.viewControllers![2] as! ProfileViewController``` I am pretty sure this would give you crash and I am not a big fan of magic numbers and force unwrapping. I can not take a chance to make this mistake on any Product I am developing. I hope my explanation has enough context to state the the above code is more dynamic and scalable. @sh-khan

Comment: no need to complicate code for future considerations what if the vc name changed , this go in scale of new code refactor

Comment: It was a suggestion to follow the good approach i feel. It is up to you at the end of the day you want to follow or not. My answer started with ```You can use below code to safely pass data to the ProfileViewController```. You can refer to any coding guidelines, I think everyone states to use optional binding instead of  force unwrapping and avoiding use of magic numbers.